# How to pass specific event type to command attribute of Tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I would like to define a callback taking different action according to different Radiobutton selected.

In the following code, I used a callback function to print the value of selected Radiobutton as well as the index in list of Radiobutton. After execution, I found IntVar() was updated after invocation of callback function, and the previous value is printed.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def RadioChange(event):
    print(radiovalue.get())
    print(radios.index(event.widget))

root = tk.Tk()

radiovalue = tk.IntVar()
radios = []
for i in range(3):
    radios.append(tk.Radiobutton(root,text="Option {}".format(i),variable=radiovalue,value=i))
    radios[i].bind("<Button-3>",RadioChange)
    radios[i].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If I used command attribute to print the value of selected Radiobutton, it worked well.(in the following code)

```
import Tkinter as tk

def RadioChange():
    print(radiovalue.get())

root = tk.Tk()

radiovalue = tk.IntVar()
radios = []
for i in range(3):
    radios.append(tk.Radiobutton(root,text="Option {}".format(i),variable=radiovalue,value=i))
    radios[i].configure(command=RadioChange)
    radios[i].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In the practice of using bind, I can bind specific event to callback function but print wrong value. In the practice of using command attribute, I can print correct value but can't assign other event except left-button-click. My question is: Is it possible to pass desired event to command attribute in order to get correct value as well as handling desired event? Or there are other solutions, such as make callback using bind() get correct value?

Comment: Unfortunatly, mouse click events raised before `radiovalue` updates. But do you really need an event? You can bind your callback to a change event of an IntVar. Is it an option?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try this option.

Comment: Yeah, it's a very good option, because you can't rely on mouse clicks since user can interact with radiobuttons with `Tab` and `Spacebar` (win) hotkeys. So, if you [traced](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) any changes, you get you radiobutton and act accordingly with just one event.